# 2extract value using regular expression in .net

Tags: .net, regex

"reportstarttime=10-18-2004:10-50-56 reportid=**12345456** reportendtime=10-18-2004:10-50-56"

How can i extract value of **reportid** which is **123456**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string GetReportId(string data)
{
    var regex = new Regex(" reportid=([0-9]+) ");
    var result = regex.Match(data);
    if (!result.Success) throw new FormatException();
    return result.Groups[1].Value;
}

var result = GetReportId("reportstarttime=10-18-2004:10-50-56 reportid=12345456 reportendtime=10-18-2004:10-50-56");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a pressing need for a regular expression? What's wrong with good ole Split?

```
var input = "reportstarttime=10-18-2004:10-50-56 reportid=12345456 reportendtime=10-18-2004:10-50-56";
var value = input.Split(' ')[1].Split('=')[1];
```